# Listview not updating based on value on Array Adapter

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I call the method below to update my listview

```
ListView list = (ListView) listView.findViewById(R.id.plan_list);
itemsList = sortAndAddSections(getItems_search(name));
ListAdapter adapter = new ListAdapter(getActivity(), itemsList);
list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

but that code is associated with a value that changes and also this is the other code

```
private ArrayList<plan_model> getItems_search(String param_cusname) {
    Cursor data = myDb.get_search_plan(pattern_email, param_name);
    int i = 0;
    while (data.moveToNext()) {
        String date = data.getString(3);
        String remarks = data.getString(4);
        items.add(new plan_model(cusname, remarks);
    }
    return items;
}
```

and this is my sorter

```
private ArrayList sortAndAddSections(ArrayList<plan_model> itemList) {

        Collections.sort(itemList);
        plan_model sectionCell;

        tempList.clear();
        tmpHeaderPositions.clear();

        String header = "";
        int addedRow = 0;
        int bgColor = R.color.alt_gray;
        for (int i = 0; i < itemList.size(); i++) {

            String remarks = itemList.get(i).getRemarks();
            String date = itemList.get(i).getDate();

            if (!(header.equals(itemList.get(i).getDate()))) {
                sectionCell = new plan_model(remarks, date);
                sectionCell.setToSectionHeader();
                tmpHeaderPositions.add(i + addedRow);
                addedRow++;
                tempList.add(sectionCell);
                header = itemList.get(i).getDate();
                bgColor = R.color.alt_gray;
            }
            sectionCell = itemList.get(i);
            sectionCell.setBgColor(bgColor);
            tempList.add(sectionCell);
            if (bgColor == R.color.alt_gray) bgColor = R.color.alt_white;
            else bgColor = R.color.alt_gray;
        }

        tmpHeaderPositions.add(tempList.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < tmpHeaderPositions.size() - 1; i++) {
            sectionCell = tempList.get(tmpHeaderPositions.get(i));
            sectionCell.setDate(sectionCell.getDate() + " (" +
                    (tmpHeaderPositions.get(i + 1) - tmpHeaderPositions.get(i) - 1) + ")");
        }

        return tempList;
    }
```

my question is the value `name` changes but my listview is not how can I update my listview? because i need to update it based on search parameter

Comment: Can you please post the code snippet which you used to call the notifydatasetchanged, including the data updating part.

Comment: actually i dont have `notifydatasetchanged` and the data update comes from the `edittext` that will be pass in my `DatabaseHelper`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `getItems_search()` add this line at the beginning:

```
items.clear();
```

Every time the value of name changes you have to do the following:

```
itemsList.clear();
itemsList = sortAndAddSections(getItems_search(name));
list.setAdapter(new ListAdapter(getActivity(), itemsList));
```

Comment: this one also add the rows only

Comment: it can't add because of `itemsList.clear()` at the beginning. So if you see items added then there's something wrong in `sortAndAddSections(getItems_search(name));`

Comment: currently checking

Comment: So for sure there is a problem in `sortAndAddSections(getItems_search(name));`

Comment: like what kind of problem?

Answer (score 1):

If your `itemList` is being updated properly, you don't need to create another instance of the adapter, just use `notifyDataSetChanged()`:

```
private void createList() {
    ListView list = (ListView) listView.findViewById(R.id.plan_list);
    itemsList = sortAndAddSections(getItems_search(name));
    adapter = new ListAdapter(getActivity(), itemsList);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private void updateList() {
    sortAndAddSections(getItems_search(name)); // Update itemList without re-assign its value, otherwise the adapter will loose reference
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

Comment: it only adds the data instead of replacing it

Comment: If I understand correctly, in this case you can clear your array before adding the other values.

Comment: huuummm let me check

Comment: itemList. But don't do `itemList = something`, just update its items

Comment: i do try the code you gave above but it adds only the data in listview

Comment: For the adapter, you have to keep a list that contains only the items that will be show. So, when your `itemList` is updated, it can't contain the previous values in case you want to replace. Otherwise, it will show it all.

Comment: so what is the best way to update it based on latest value? still cant find the right code for it